# Finding UnMatched Users from a Table

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, grails-orm

I have an array of usernames as users:[Test1,Test2].I have to loop through this array and should find the unmatched usernames from table b.I have written the query as below:

```
def usersArray = []
def find

params.users.each{

        find= sql.rows("select distinct name from table a,table b where a.id=b.id and b.name!=:n",[n:it])

        if(find.size >0)
        {
           def usList = ["nm":find]
           usersArray.push(usList);
        }
    }
```

From the above solution in my result i see both Test 1 and Test 2 even though they match.How should i change the query to display only the unmatched users?

Comment: Do you have to use SQL statements like that or can you use a Domain class and GORM?

Comment: @ Joshua -Can you suggest how to do it GORM way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might go about solving this problem. This assumes you have a domain class called `User` with a property called `name` which you want to match on.

```
// given a list of user names
​List users = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4']

// find all the users that match those names, and collect the matched names into a List
List matched = User.findAll("from User as u where u.name in (:names)", [names: users]).collect { it.name }

// remove the matched names from the user list and arrive at an 'unmatched' names list
List unmatched = users.minus(matched)​​
```

This was written off the top of my head so please forgive any typos or other random assumptions.

**UPDATED**
Since you seem set on using SQL you might be able to do something like this instead

```
List users = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4']
List placeholders = []
users.each { placeholders << '?' }
String select = "select distinct name from table a,table b where a.id=b.id and b.name in (${placeholders.join(',')})"
List matched = sql.rows(select, users)
List unmatched = users.minus(matched)​​
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.Basically i have to join two tables to get my expected result and i edited my question too.I am not sure whether GORM can achieve it.

Comment: Oh, please remove that sql. It's an affront to common decency!

Comment: @Strawberry Trust me. I still taste my lunch for the 3rd time having it there. However the OP really wants SQL.

Comment: At least use a post 1996 join syntax

Comment: @Strawberry The query is the OPs not mine. I'm just showing how to use an IN. How they do their joins is up to them. Perhaps, edit the answer and show in a comment a better SQL statement (as a bonus)? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Another way - count the existing rows which match the parameter name, then push those that have zero  (forgive the bad syntax):

```
....
numberFound = sql.rows("select count(*)from table a where a.name=:n",[n:it])
if(numberFound = 0)
{
   def usList = ["nm":find]
   usersArray.push(usList);
}
...
```

Comment: @ KenOn10 - From the above querry i will get only the count but not the usernames ryt?